# React component tree close previously opened parent node

Tags: reactjs

I have created a react component tree for navigation.
You can see it working in the below codepen.

[React Component Tree](https://codepen.io/phaniwithu/pen/wjXoPL)

```
    let navConfigData = {
  isDashboardVisible: true,
  tierOneLinks: [
    {
      name: "First Page",
      iconName: "star",
      iconAbbreviation: "FP",
      tierTwoItems: [
        {
          name: "Tier 2 Page",
          iconName: "star",
          iconAbbreviation: "FP",
          tierThreeItems: [
            {
              name: "Tier 3 Page",
              iconName: "star",
              iconAbbreviation: "FP",
              path: "#"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Tier 2 sec Page",
          iconName: "star",
          iconAbbreviation: "FP",
          path: "#"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Second Page",
      iconName: "",
      iconAbbreviation: "SP",
      path: "#"
    },
    {
      name: "Third Page",
      iconAbbreviation: "TP",
      path: "#",
      tierTwoItems: [
        {
          name: "Tier 2 Page",
          iconName: "star",
          iconAbbreviation: "FP",
          tierThreeItems: [
            {
              name: "Tier 3 Page",
              iconName: "star",
              iconAbbreviation: "FP",
              path: "#"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Tier 2 sec Page",
          iconName: "star",
          iconAbbreviation: "FP",
          path: "#"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Fourth Page",
      iconName: "send",
      iconAbbreviation: "FO",
      path: "#"
    }
  ],
  supportLinks: [
    {
      name: "First Support Page",
      iconName: "settings",
      iconAbbreviation: "FI",
      path: "#"
    },
    {
      name: "Second Support Page",
      iconName: "security",
      iconAbbreviation: "SE",
      path: "#"
    },
    {
      name: "Third Support Page",
      iconName: "help",
      iconAbbreviation: "TH",
      path: "#"
    }
  ]
};


class NavigationDrawerTierThree extends React.Component {

  onClick = evt => {
    this.props.onSelect(this.props.tierThree.name);
  };


  render() {
    const { tierThree, selectedTierThreeLink } = this.props;
debugger;
    return (
        <a
          className="mdc-list-item my-nav-drawer__tier-three"          
          onClick={this.onClick}
        >
          <span className="my-nav-drawer__tier-two-label">
            {tierThree.name}
          </span>
        </a>
    );
  }
}


 class NavigationDrawerTierTwo extends React.Component {
  // static propTypes = {
  //   tierTwo: object.isRequired,
  //   showNavIcon: bool,
  //   onSelect: func.isRequired,
  //   selectedTierTwoLink: string.isRequired
  // };

  state = { tierTwoIsExpanded: false };

  onClick = evt => {
    debugger;
    this.props.onSelect(this.props.tierTwo.name, "tier2");
    const { tierTwoIsExpanded } = this.state;
    this.setState({ tierTwoIsExpanded: !tierTwoIsExpanded });
  };

  getArrowIcon = () => {
    return this.state.tierTwoIsExpanded ? (
      <span class="material-icons cdk-nav-drawer__tier-two-icon">></span>
    ) : (
      <span class="material-icons cdk-nav-drawer__tier-two-icon">
        ^
      </span>
    );
  };

  getAnchorClassBasedOnTier = () => {
      return this.props.showNavIcon
        ? "cdk-nav-drawer__tier-two"
        : "cdk-nav-drawer__tier-three";
  };

  getLabelClassBasedOnTier = () => {
      return this.props.showNavIcon
        ? "cdk-nav-drawer__tier-two-label"
        : "cdk-nav-drawer__tier-three-label";
  };

  render() {
    const { tierTwo, showNavIcon, selectedTierTwoLink } = this.props;
    const { tierTwoIsExpanded } = this.state;

debugger;
    return (
      <div>
        <a
          className="mdc-list-item my-nav-drawer__tier-two"   
          onClick={this.onClick}
          >
          {showNavIcon && this.getArrowIcon()}
          <span className="my-nav-drawer__tier-two-label">
            {tierTwo.name}
          </span>
        </a>
        {tierTwoIsExpanded && this.props.children}
        </div>

    );
  }
}

class NavigationDrawerTierOneAnchor extends React.Component{
  //   static propTypes = {
  //   tierOne: object.isRequired,
  //   onSelect: func.isRequired,
  //   selectedTierOneLink: string.isRequired
  // };

 // state = { tierIsExpanded: false };

onClick = evt => {
    this.props.onSelect(this.props.tierOne.name, "tier1");
    // const { tierIsExpanded } = this.state;
    // this.setState({ tierIsExpanded: !tierIsExpanded });
  };

render(){
    const { tierOne, selectedTierOneLink, expanded } = this.props;
  return(
    <div>
        <a
          className="mdc-list-item my-nav-drawer__tier-one"
          href={tierOne.path}
          onClick={this.onClick}
          ref={a => {
            this.anchor = a;
          }}
        >
       <span className="cdk-nav-drawer__tier-one-label">
            {tierOne.name}
          </span>
      </a>
        {expanded && this.props.children}
      </div>
  );
}

}
class NavigationDrawerAppTiers extends React.Component {
  // static propTypes = {
  //   tierOneArray: array.isRequired,
  //   onToggleExpand: func.isRequired,
  //   onSelect: func.isRequired,
  //   selectedTierOneLink: string.isRequired,
  //   selectedTierTwoLink: string.isRequired,
  //   selectedTierThreeLink: string.isRequired,
  //   expandedTierOneName: string.isRequired
  // };

  render(){
        const { tierOneArray, onSelect, selectedTierOneLink, selectedTierTwoLink, selectedTierThreeLink, expandedTierOneName } = this.props;
        return (
          <div className="mdc-drawer__content my-nav-drawer__app-tiers">
            <nav className="mdc-list">
          {tierOneArray.map((tierOneLink, index) => (
            <NavigationDrawerTierOneAnchor
              tierOne={tierOneLink}
              onSelect={onSelect}
              key={index}
              expanded={tierOneLink.name === this.props.expandedTierOneName}
              selectedTierOneLink={selectedTierOneLink}
            >
              {(tierOneLink.tierTwoItems || []).map((tierTwoItem, index) => (
                <NavigationDrawerTierTwo
                  tierTwo={tierTwoItem}
                  onSelect={onSelect}
                  selectedTierTwoLink={selectedTierTwoLink}
                  showNavIcon={
                    (tierTwoItem.tierThreeItems &&
                      tierTwoItem.tierThreeItems.length > 0) ||
                    false
                  }
                >
                  {(tierTwoItem.tierThreeItems || []).map(
                    (tierThreeItem, index) => (
                      <NavigationDrawerTierThree
                        tierThree={tierThreeItem}
                        onSelect={onSelect}
                        selectedTierThreeLink={selectedTierThreeLink}
                        />
                    )
                  )}
                </NavigationDrawerTierTwo>
              ))}
            </NavigationDrawerTierOneAnchor>
          ))}
        </nav>
          </div>
        );
  }

}


class NavigationDrawer extends React.Component {
 // static propTypes = {
 //    navConfig: object.isRequired
 //  };

state = {
    isDrawerCollapsed: false,
    selectedTierOneLink: "",
    selectedTierTwoLink: "",
    selectedTierThreeLink: "",
    expandedTierOneName: ""
  };

onSelect = (selectedLinkName, selectedTier) => {
    if(selectedTier == "tier1"){
      if (selectedLinkName === this.state.selectedTierOneLink) {
        // User clicked on the same link again
        this.setState(state => ({
          expandedTierOneName: state.expandedTierOneName?"":selectedLinkName
        }))
      } else {
        this.setState(state=>({
          expandedTierOneName:selectedLinkName
        }))
      }
      this.setState(state => ({ selectedTierOneLink: selectedLinkName }));
      this.setState(state => ({ selectedTierTwoLink: "" }));
    } else if (selectedTier == "tier2"){
      this.setState(state => ({ selectedTierTwoLink: selectedLinkName }));
      this.setState(state => ({ selectedTierThreeLink: "" }));
    } else {
      this.setState(state => ({ selectedTierThreeLink: selectedLinkName }));
      this.setState(state => ({ selectedTierTwoLink: "" }));

    }
  };

    render(){
          const { navConfig } = this.props;
        return(
        <nav className="mdc-drawer mdc-drawer--permanent mdc-typography my-nav-drawer">
            <div className="my-nav-drawer__links">
              <NavigationDrawerAppTiers
              tierOneArray={navConfig.tierOneLinks}
              onSelect={this.onSelect}
              selectedTierOneLink={this.state.selectedTierOneLink}
              selectedTierTwoLink={this.state.selectedTierTwoLink}
              selectedTierThreeLink={this.state.selectedTierThreeLink}
              expandedTierOneName={this.state.expandedTierOneName}
            />
            </div>
        </nav>
        );
    }

}




React.render(
    <NavigationDrawer navConfig={navConfigData}/>, 
    document.body
);
```

The component is max upto three levels and I don't want it to achieve currently with recursion.

I am looking for a behavior to close the previously opened Parent tree node after selecting any child from another parent tree.

To explain in detail from the Codepen example, I need help on the below scenario.

Currently if no child Items are selected, only One parent node will be toggled.

I need help in achieving the below scenario.

1. Click on any child Item from First page,
   Now clicking on the Third page should not collapse the First Page(since an item is selected from First Page), First Page should collapse when any child item from Third page is selected.

If no child Item is selected from Third page and Third Page is clicked again then all the opened parent nodes (First page and third page) should be collapsed.

Could someone help me with modifying the codpen.

Below code throws initialState is not defined

```
    class NavigationDrawer extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
     navConfig: object.isRequired
   };

  initialState = this.props.navConfig.tierOneLinks.reduce((acc, { name }) => {
  acc[name] = false;
  return acc;
}, {});

state = {
     expanded: initialState,
    isDrawerCollapsed: false,
    selectedTierOneLink: "",
    selectedTierTwoLink: "",
    selectedTierThreeLink: "",
    expandedTierOneName: ""
  };

onSelect = (selectedLinkName, selectedTier) => {
    if(selectedTier == "tier1"){
      if (selectedLinkName === this.state.selectedTierOneLink) {
        // User clicked on the same link again
        this.setState(state => ({
          expandedTierOneName: state.expandedTierOneName?"":selectedLinkName
        }))
      } else {
        this.setState(state=>({
          expandedTierOneName:selectedLinkName
        }))
      }
      this.setState(state => ({ selectedTierOneLink: selectedLinkName }));
      this.setState(state => ({ selectedTierTwoLink: "" }));
    } else if (selectedTier == "tier2"){
      this.setState(state => ({ selectedTierTwoLink: selectedLinkName }));
      this.setState(state => ({ selectedTierThreeLink: "" }));
    } else {
      this.setState(state => ({ selectedTierThreeLink: selectedLinkName }));
      this.setState(state => ({ selectedTierTwoLink: "" }));

    }
  };

    render(){
          const { navConfig } = this.props;

        return(
        <nav className="mdc-drawer mdc-drawer--permanent mdc-typography my-nav-drawer">
            <div className="my-nav-drawer__links">
              <NavigationDrawerAppTiers
              tierOneArray={navConfig.tierOneLinks}
              onSelect={this.onSelect}
              selectedTierOneLink={this.state.selectedTierOneLink}
              selectedTierTwoLink={this.state.selectedTierTwoLink}
              selectedTierThreeLink={this.state.selectedTierThreeLink}
              expandedTierOneName={this.state.expandedTierOneName}
            />
            </div>
        </nav>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not simply set the menu to the default state and then open the new toggle?

Comment: Could you please help in the Codepen ? Having a hard time to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to edit the Codepen and do all the work for you, but I'll give you a general idea of how to achieve your requirements.

> Click on any child Item from First page, Now clicking on the Third page should not collapse the First Page

To accomplish this, you need a separate `expanded` state for each `tierOneLinks`:

```
state = {
  expanded: {},
};
```

Then you can use `state.expanded[tierOne.name]` to check if the tier one panel is expanded, and expand it with

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  expanded: {
    ...prevState.expanded, // leave other panels expanded
    [tierOne.name]: true,
  },
}));
```

> First Page should collapse when any child item from Third page is selected.

To accomplish this, the child item's `onClick` handler need to call a callback function (from the parent component, passed as props) that does the following:

```
this.setState({
  expanded: {
    [tierOne.name] : true, // collapse all other panels
  }
})
```

> If no child Item is selected from Third page and Third Page is clicked again then all the opened parent nodes (First page and third page) should be collapsed.

To accomplish this, check if the current page is already expanded, and if so, set all panels to collapsed:

```
if (state.expanded[tierOne.name]) this.setState({ expanded: {} });
```

#### Alternative

Use a `Set` or array as the state for the list of expanded pages.
You need to create a copy of the previous state when you want to update it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am having a hard time implementing your suggestions. I am not asking to do from scratch. I have done some work in Codepen. could you please provide your suggestion in Codepen.

Comment: Thanks a lot, If i use reduce inside the class I get initialState is not defined. Am I missing any thing

Comment: Does my link work? Can you update the code there and link it?

Comment: I have updated the link.   https://codesandbox.io/s/00ypm7wj9w . Also if there are no child elements selected then at any point of time only One parent should be expanded and collapsed

Comment: You added the `initialState` in the wrong place. For your newly mentioned criteria, you just have to add an extra check: https://codesandbox.io/s/vnnm41480y. See the changes i made: https://www.diffchecker.com/CRHHX47t

Comment: We are almost done, Thanks for your patience. The initial config data is passed as props <NavigationDrawer navConfig={navConfig} /> In that case I would receive that as props in NavigationDrawer Comp. In the codepen/sandbox example the navconfig is directly available it is directly available. Should I use any react lifecycle methods to get that initialstate.

Comment: On second thought, we don't actually need to define an initial state since falsy value (undefined) would suffice. See https://codesandbox.io/s/vnnm41480y

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a lot. You saved my time. I will award the bounty as I am unable to vote now.